# Show all products from a specific store?

Tags: magento-1.8, database, sql

Is it possible to show all articles from a specific store?

I know I can filter for website, but it does not seem to be possible to filter for store.

Maybe there is a SQL query which I can use?

Comment: Are you using any extension?

Comment: I use many extensions.

Comment: I mean for articles?

Comment: Im not sure, i don't think so.

Comment: Magento default doesn't have articles.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, is the question clear now?

Comment: No. Its not clear. What do you mean by articles?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, article = product

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is **not possible** to filter products per `store view`, per websites yes it is possible.

What you have to do is to group your products by `categories`, then you set that category just for some `storeview`, afterthat you can **filter** your category per `storeview` and you will be able to get his products.

Comment: Sorry, I mean per store, not store view.